What is the meaning of “putana”? (torta putana)
I found recipes for “torta putana”, a sweet cake made either with stale bread or with polenta.
However, I am having a tough time understanding the meaning or etymology behind the curious name. Both the articles that I have linked mention an origin story where someone exclaimed “La putana!” during an incident involving the cake. However, I was unable to find out what that means and why someone would say that.

Note that the earliest news about the “putana” cake date back to the early 15th century when Vicenza (its  place of origin) was still part of the Serenissima Republic of Venice. https://www.vicenzatoday.it/cucina/putana-storia-ricetta-dolce-tipico-vicentino.html

@Hachi Thanks for sharing the link. I see that includes another possible explanation for the meaning and origin of the name.

The standard Italian version is puttana, here used as a generic swearword. However, when pronounced in the accent of the Veneto region, where the cake comes from, it sounds more like putana, since double-consonants are often pronounced weakly in that region.

Assuming this is true, why would someone exclaim "la puttana!" when something surprising happened? Is it some sort of idiom?

It's just used as a generic swearword, the way an English speaker would exclaim "fuck!" or "shit!".
